# How to write test for construction of a class using Dio?

Tags: flutter, mockito, flutter-test, dio

I have a class which will fetch the `imgUrl` on first creation in the constructor.
And I need to write a test to make sure that the `get` method of `Dio` instance is called.
However, I have trouble that the fetch result returns `null` instead of `Future` so that I cannot call `then`.

---

The class:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class DogBreed with ChangeNotifier {
  @JsonKey(ignore: true)
  final Dio dio;

  final String id;
  final String bred_for;
  final String breed_group;
  final String life_span;
  final String name;
  final String origin;
  final String temperament;
  final String description;
  final Measurement height;
  final Measurement weight;

  var imgUrl = '';

  DogBreed({
    this.dio,
    this.id,
    this.bred_for,
    this.breed_group,
    this.life_span,
    this.name,
    this.origin,
    this.temperament,
    this.description,
    this.height,
    this.weight,
  }) {
    dio.get(
      'xxxxx,
      queryParameters: {
        'breed_id': id,
        'limit': 1,
      },
    ).then((result) {
      final List data = result.data;

      if (result.statusCode == 200) {
        if (data.isNotEmpty) {
          imgUrl = result.data[0]['url'];
        } else {
          imgUrl = NO_IMAGE_AVAILABLE_URL;
        }
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
  }

  factory DogBreed.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DogBreedFromJson(json);
}
```

My test:

```
class MockDio extends Mock implements Dio {}

void main() {
  MockDio mockDio;

  setUp(() {
    mockDio = MockDio();
  });

  test(
    "fetch the imageUrl on constructor",
    () async {
      when(mockDio.get(any))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Response(data: 'url', statusCode: 200));

      final newBreedProvider = DogBreed(
        dio: mockDio,
        id: '12',
      );

      verify(mockDio.get(
        'xxxx',
        queryParameters: {
          'breed_id': 12,
          'limit': 1,
        },
      ));
    },
  );
}
```

Result when run test:

```
dart:core                                                           Object.noSuchMethod
package:practises/projects/dog_facts/providers/dog_breed.dart 46:7  new DogBreed
test/projects/dog_facts/providers/dog_breed_test.dart 24:32         main.<fn>

NoSuchMethodError: The method 'then' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: then<Null>(Closure: (Response<dynamic>) => Null)
```

Could anyone help me to figure out how to write this test or suggest me a new way of implementing so that I can write a test on this one?

Comment: I think this answers your post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321828/unit-test-how-to-mock-parameters-of-third-party-library-class-dio-in-flutter/64935059#64935059

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why, it's my mistake that I need to provide `queryParameters` for `get` method in the test. It should be:

```
      when(
        mockPdio.get(
          any,
          queryParameters: anyNamed('queryParameters'),
        ),
      ).thenAnswer((_) async => Response(data: 'url', statusCode: 200));
```

Cheers.