# Unit test - How to mock parameters of third-party-library class Dio in flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, mockito, flutter-test

I am trying to test a simple repository class which make a network call using the Dio package that is a dependency injection. Requirement of the Http.post is to send a Map object to a URL with the headers of `'Content-Type': 'application/json`. You can see this below:

```
class AuthenticateUserRemoteDataSourceImpl
    implements AuthenticateUserRepository {
  final Dio httpClient;

  AuthenticateUserRemoteDataSourceImpl({@required this.httpClient});

  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, AuthenticateUser>> getAuthenticateUser(
      String email, String password) async {
    final url = 'API_URL';

    final Map<String, String> jsonPayload = {
      "email": email,
      "password": password
    };

    Response response = await httpClient.post('{$url}api/users/authenticate',
        data: jsonPayload,
        options: Options(headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}));
  }
}
```

I am trying to make sure this method is covered by unit test, however I am having difficult verify the named parameters with the Dio package. I can verify that the `dioClient.post` is actually called however, I am having trouble with mocking the name parameters of 'data' and 'options'.

I want to test that it gets called with `Map<String, String>` for the body, and also I would like to test the headers that are sent, I want to check that is it called with the `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`. This will be useful as well when I need to unit test Authenticated dio get/post/put requests.

This is the test that I have so far, which as mentioned before I can verify that the mocked function is called, but not verifying the name params.

```
  group('getAuthenticateUser', () {
    final tResponse = Response(statusCode: 200, data: {"title": "success"});

    test(
        'should perform a post request to the the API with the application/json header',
        () async {
      // arrange
      when(dioClient.post(any,
              data: anyNamed('data'), options: anyNamed('options')))
          .thenAnswer((Invocation invocation) async => tResponse);

      // act
      await dataSource.getAuthenticateUser(tEmail, tPassword);

      // assert
      verify(dioClient.post(any,
          data: anyNamed('data'), options: anyNamed('options')));
    });
  });
```

Thanks for your helps, I am just getting started with unit testing so any help or pointers will be great,

Thanks, Sam

@LoVe
[image]

*Update*

I have implemented your mock class which worked great, and I think it was the thing that I was missing for sure. I have updated my test but cannot understand where I am going wrong now?

test.dart

```
class MockOptions extends Mock implements Options {
  final Map<String, dynamic> headers;
  //also add any other parameters you want to mock as fields in this class

  MockOptions({this.headers});
}


test(
   'should perform a post request to the the API with the application/json header',
    () async {
        // arrange
        Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};

        when(mockDio.post('path', options: anyNamed('options')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => Response(data: {}));

        // act
        dataSource.getAuthenticateUser(tEmail, tPassword);

        // assert
        verify(mockDio.post('path', options: MockOptions(headers: headers)));
    });
```

and the method file looking like this:

```
  @override
  Future<Either<Failure, AuthenticateUser>> getAuthenticateUser(
      String email, String password) async {

    await this.httpClient.post('path',
        data: {},
        options: Options(headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}));
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

### Use [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter), new package for mocking `Dio` requests.

You can simply replace your injected `Dio`'s `httpClientAdapter` with `DioAdapter()` of [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter):

example from [examples](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter/example) of [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter)

```dart
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:http_mock_adapter/http_mock_adapter.dart';

void main() async {
  final dio = Dio();
  final dioAdapter = DioAdapter();

  dio.httpClientAdapter = dioAdapter;

  const path = 'https://example.com';

  dioAdapter
      ..onGet(
        path,
        (request) => request.reply(200, {'message': 'Successfully mocked GET!'}),
      )
      ..onGet(
        path,
        (request) => request.reply(200, {'message': 'Successfully mocked POST!'}),
      );

  final onGetResponse = await dio.get(path);
  print(onGetResponse.data); // {message: Successfully mocked GET!}

  final onPostResponse = await dio.post(path);
  print(onPostResponse.data); // {message: Successfully mocked POST!}
}
```

You can also use, `DioInterceptor` of [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter), which can be added to `dio.interceptor` list.

view second example in [examples](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter/example) file of [http_mock_adapter](https://pub.dev/packages/http_mock_adapter)

Answer (score 1):

to test that this method

```
Response response = await httpClient.post('{$url}api/users/authenticate',
        data: jsonPayload,
        options: Options(headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}));
```

is called with proper arguments you should create an `MockOption` class and pass an instance of it to the function call in your test

also you should create an object of type `Map<String,dynamic>` (or whatever types the json uses) and pass that object also to the same method call to the `data` parameter

then you use `Mockito`'s methods to verify that your method was called with the test arguments you have passed

and also to test the headers you do as I said here regarding the map:

> also you should create an object of type `Map<String,dynamic>` (or
>   whatever types the json uses) and pass that object also to the same
>   method call

Please have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61317757/9142279)

**Update:**

so for example to mock the `options` parameter you can do:

```
class MockOptions extends Mock implements Options{
  final Map<String,dynamic> headers;
  //also add any other parameters you want to mock as fields in this class

  MockOptions(this.headers);
}
```

then, in your test, you do:

```
final MockOptions mockOptions = MockOptions({
              //mocked map data here
            });
```

Comment: Hey bud, thank you for your answer. I still could not figure this out at all. I have come back to it after a couple of weeks off and still no joy. I have put a bounty of it now, if possible would you be able to give me more indication how the mock response would look like?

When I try and Mock the Options class, I cannot add any named params to the class is this a restriction with the Mock class?

Comment: you mean you can't replace `data: anyNamed('data')` with, for example, `data: myData` ?

Comment: I have added a screenshot on the original question

Comment: Thank you, I did not think of adding params to the mock class. Very good

Comment: I have updated my question with an updated, after using your named param solution, can you spot what is wrong my updated test? In the `when` func I am passing the `anyNamed` as this doesn't need to be an instance of the `MockOptions` surely. I just have to verify that the method is called with the correct option. Or have I misunderstood again?

Comment: @SamKelham thank you, can you provide what error are you getting?

Comment: I think your test is not passing because you need to pass the mocked options as a parameter to your `getAuthenticateUser` method. Basically everything that need to be tested should be sent in the parameter list of the method you are testing so you can control it at test time

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the test and you have to inject the mock into the dio and the test

```
   Class httpadapter {
    final Opstions? options;
    final Dio client;
   
   httpadapter(this.client, {this.options});

    Future<dynamic> request( String method  dynamic body) {
  
     if (method == 'post') {
        response = await client.post(url,
       data: body, options: options ??  Options(headers: defaultheaders ));
   }
 }
}
 
  Unit Test
   
     class clientspy extends Mock implements dio {}

     class mockoption extends Mock implements Options {}

void main() {
      late httpadapter sut;
      late clientSpy client;
      late string url;
      late mockOptions mockoptions;

  setup(() {
    client = clientSpy();
    mockOptions = MockOptions();
    sut = HttpAdapter(client, options: mockOptions);
    url = 'fake_url';
  });

     When mockPostCall() => when(() => client.post(any(),
        data: any(named: 'data'), options: any(named: 'options')));

    void mockPost(int statusCode, {Map? body}) =>
        mockPostCall().thenAnswer((_) async => Response(
            data: body ?? {"any_key": "any_value"},
            statusCode: statusCode,
            requestOptions: RequestOptions()));

    When mockOpstionCall() => when(() => mockOptions.headers);

    void mockOpstions({Map? data}) {
       final defaultHeaders = data?.cast<String, String>() ?? {}
      ..addAll(
          {'content-type': 'application/json', 'accept': 'application/json'});
      mockOpstionCall().thenAnswer((_) => defaultHeaders);
    }


    test('Should call post with correct values with mor one param headers', () async {
      mockOpstions( data:{'any_header': 'any_value'});
      await sut.request(
          url: url,
          method: 'post',
          body: {'any_key': 'any_value'});

      verify(() => client.post(url, data: {
            "any_key": "any_value"
          }, options: mockOptions));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**